# Unity3D v5 setting up a vertex shader from a old custom shader

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this custom shader that worked in old unity versions, but now we've upgraded to v5 and they changed the rules for shaders. It is required now that they are made through "vertex shaders". Can someone help us figuring out how to convert our shader into a vertex shader? Or any other way, as long as it is v5 compatible?

```
Shader "Depth Mask" {
    SubShader {
        Tags {"Queue" = "Geometry-10"}
        Lightning Off
        ZTest LEqual
        ZWrite On
        ColorMask 0
        Pass {}
    }
}
```

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Properties.html <- States the removal.

Thanks in advance,
Ivo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Shader *is* Unity5 compatible (you only misspelled Lighting):

```
Shader "Depth Mask" {
    SubShader {
        Tags {"Queue" = "Geometry-10"}
        Lighting Off
        ZTest LEqual
        ZWrite On
        ColorMask 0
        Pass {}
    }
}
```

The link you provided to Unity 5's manual does not relate to your problem.